we have updated the clientsecret value in app registration as it was expired but the web url is not able to identify the new secret value
We updated the clientsecret value in app registration as it was expired but the url webapp application url is not able to read the new value and throwing below error:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app 'XXXXXXXXX'. Trace ID: 619dXXXXXXX900 Correlation ID: 5eXXXXXXXXa2 Timestamp: 2024-04-23 13:31:07Z.
we tried passing the client secret value both from key-vault and directly passing it in configuration but its not working in either case.
any immediate reply will be highly appreciated.
thnks !!
we expected the webapp application to read the updated new secretvalue but its not able to read the new value.

Is this helping? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275176/invalid-client-secret-provided

@vikashk Try generating new client secret and make sure to pass client secret value not ID


Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app 'XXXXXXXXX'. Trace ID: 619dXXXXXXX900 Correlation ID: 5eXXXXXXXXa2 Timestamp: 2024-04-23 13:31:07Z.

This error usually occurs when, client secrets value is incorrect, or the  client secret value is not associated with the same client_id.

To resolve the error, I followed below steps:
-Registered an Web-Application using Microsoft Identity Platform
appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "DomainName",
    "TenantId": "<Tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<client_id>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}


Now, verify the New Client secret which created in App registration with secrets.json :

Output:

